# HTTP - Status Code

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, http, http-status-codes

I'm using Spring Boot and controllers I'm feeling difficulty to treat some errors, for this reason I have some questions about the most appropriate status for each of the following situation:

1. **PUT** Object no Id

Put the URL **localhost:8080/users/1** with a JSON without the Id attribute.

2. **PUT** Object with different parameter Id

Put the URL **localhost:8080/users/1** with a JSON with Id 2, ie, different from what was passed in the parameter.

3. **GET** with invalid parameter

GET on the URL **localhost:8080/users/search?sex=ABC**, or an invalid sex for the system (the correct would be sex = male or female?).

4. JSON POST with id

Performing a **POST** in order to persist the data (create) but with id.

Comment: Is there a question you're trying to ask here? What status code to return for these operations? Also, in number 1, it looks like you did give an id to the user. And in number 2, you used id 1, not id 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1. Id is in the uri : no error

Case 3. "400 Bad request" is acceptable. (client should not retry the exact same request)

Cases 2. and 4. Just ignore the Id from the body and return 200 or return a "400 Bad Request"

Note that the **id shouldn't be seen as an attribute** of the resource: it is a part of the resource identifier.